# make a phone call from a MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay, phone-call

i'm trying to make a phone call when i click on alertDialog button,this alertdialog attached to a mapview at every geopoint. I think i'm doing something wrong here 
this is my logcat:

```
02-04 16:21:22.578: E/AndroidRuntime(432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 16:21:22.578: E/AndroidRuntime(432): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 16:21:22.578: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at fsg.mpssri.MEGAMAG.ListItimizedOverlay$CallMeclass.access$0(ListItimizedOverlay.java:88)
02-04 16:21:22.578: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at fsg.mpssri.MEGAMAG.ListItimizedOverlay$1.onClick(ListItimizedOverlay.java:66)
02-04 16:21:22.578: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
02-04 16:21:22.578: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 16:21:22.578: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-04 16:21:22.578: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-04 16:21:22.578: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 16:21:22.578: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-04 16:21:22.578: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-04 16:21:22.578: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-04 16:21:22.578: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here my code for the class of ListItimizedOverlay

```
package fsg.mpssri.MEGAMAG;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class ListItimizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    public CallMeclass clme;
    public String phoneNum = "55-223-014";
    public GeoloMe geololome; 
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> arrayListOverlayItem = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    public ListItimizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    public ListItimizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context pContext) 
    {
      super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
      this.context = pContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrayListOverlayItem.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrayListOverlayItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        OverlayItem item = arrayListOverlayItem.get(index);
          AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
          dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon__telephone);
          dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
          dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
           //phoneNum = item.getSnippet();
          dialog.setPositiveButton("call us", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //geololome.makeUrcall(phoneNum);
                Toast.makeText(context, "azerty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

              clme.goCallMe(phoneNum);


            }


        });
          dialog.show();
          return true;
    }

    public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem overlay) 
    {
        arrayListOverlayItem.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }




private class CallMeclass extends Activity{

    private void goCallMe(String phonenumber ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new
                Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                        Uri.parse(phonenumber));
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

}
```

Hope you can help me my friends
thanks

Comment: callMeClass shouldn't extend activity. it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not instantiating `clme` anywhere.  That's why you get the NPE.

Do `clme = new CallMeclass();` first before calling the method.

You don't need the CallMeclass here. You can directly fire the intent from your click handler.

Comment: thanks a lot @Mus
so as you said: i'm adding now this : 
clme =new CallMeclass();
into onTap method but i still get problems in logcat:

'02-04 16:46:38.977: E/AndroidRuntime(483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 16:46:38.977: E/AndroidRuntime(483): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 16:46:38.977: E/AndroidRuntime(483):at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
02-04 16:46:38.977: E/AndroidRuntime(483):at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)'

but should i add oncreate() method ??

Comment: @njzk2 
i think i need "extend activity " because i'm using 
startActivity() for the intent .

Comment: what's wrong with my code??
i modify this
 
`dialog.setPositiveButton("call us", new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
          clme =new CallMeclass();
    
       // clme.goCallMe(phoneNum);
        Intent i = new
                  Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                          Uri.parse(phoneNum));
          clme.startActivity(i);
    
   }

   
  });`

i still got same problems :(

Comment: thanks @Mus
i find a solution !!!! 
i make another intent to an activity
and there i make my call with this code
`Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);                
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +55324567));
        startActivity(callIntent);`